# Unable to connect to my AWS RDS MS SQL SERVER on SMSS on my local laptop

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I created a AWS RDS MS SQL Server database and obviously I want to connect to it from my local pc/laptop. I will share screenshots to show my network settings.

This is the error:

[image]

My connectivity & security details:

[image]

The Inbound rules when clicking on the VPC security groups related to this DB (I have added my own IP address:

[image]

I have no experience in networking & security, so it might be something I've missed.

What should I do to make it possible? I don't want public access to the database.

Update 1: added screenshots of my Network ACLs associated with the VPC that's related to the DB.

[image]

Comment: Does your VPC have the [default network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#default-network-acl). Also, see [troubleshooting](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/).

Comment: @jarmod I have added a screenshot

Comment: Did you follow the troubleshooter? I see you modified inbound NACLS (unnecessarily because of rule 100). What about outbound NACLs?

Comment: @jarmod I removed both modified rules, now it's back at default again. but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking that the subnets associated with the subnet group for this database are public.

As you mentioned, it is not safe to have a database publicly accessible. You can place it in a private subnet and only access it via a tunnel. Here is a [link](https://www.virtualtothecore.com/tunnel-all-your-remote-connections-through-ssh-with-a-linux-jumpbox/) for that info. Hope it helps.